# Error con función unset() dentro de una variable

Tags: php, wamp, registro

estoy haciendo un registro de usuarios y en el código para que devuelvan los errores

> ```
> function borrarErrores(){
>     $borrado=false;
>
>     if(isset($_SESSION['errores'])){
>         $_SESSION['errores']=null;
>         $borrado= session_unset($_SESSION['errores']);
>     }
>
>
>     if(isset($_SESSION['completado'])){
>         $_SESSION['completado']=null;
>         unset($_SESSION['completado']);
>     }
>
>     return $borrado;
> }
> ```

Me da un error en la línea de la variable $borrado diciendo que a esa función no se le pueden pasar parámetros pero si cambio esa función por unset() simplemente también me sale un error. Que alternativa sería la más adecuada?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Que error te marca?

Comment: Tambien comentarte que a la funcion `session_unset()` no se le pasan parametros.

Comment: @MarioGuiber Estoy aprendiendo PHP y el instructor es lo que hizo pero a él no le salía ese error, hay alguna otra forma para conseguir lo mismo y que no de error?

Comment: La solución no va en la pregunta, por favor considera publicarla en. La zona de respuestas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`session_unset` borra todas las variables de `SESSION`, en su lugar, utiliza

```
unset($_SESSION['errores'])
```

Comment: Solucionado!. Dejo el código final por si a alguien que viene buscando le pasa

Answer (score 0):

Tuve el mismo problema con el mismo curso de victor robles, la solucion que yo encontre fue quitarle el session_unset y prescindir de la variable borrado por lo que ahora mi metodo es una funcion que no retorna nada, solo ejecuta la accion, pero realiza lo mismo que se hace en el video y sin marcar error. Es como dijeron anteriormente session_unset no recibe parametros y por eso marca el error.

[image: Por aca adjunto como queda el metodo]

Comment: Por favor agrega el código como texto y no como imagen. Qué diferencia tiene tu respuesta con la respuesta aceptada? Te recomiendo leer [answer]